# How to echo a EOF in bash?

Tags: bash

After search it seems the ascii of EOF is `-1`,but how can I `echo` it out?

My purpose of doing this is to test whether it behaves the same as pressing `ctrl-d` if I just `echo` out `EOF`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to echo out an EOF. An EOF can only be generated either by reaching the end of a file or by invoking the keypress bound to the `eof` terminal setting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> by default) when the file being read is bound to the terminal.

Comment: isn't `EOF` defined as `-1` in stdio.h? why can't echo it out if we know its ascii value?

Comment: So what. An `int` with the value of -1 (or 4294967295 if we consider the unsigned version) can't possibly be a character anyway since characters can only have a value from 0 to 255 inclusive.

Comment: how do you know it's an `int` in the first place?

Comment: Because I do things like look at the `fgetc(3)` man page.

Answer (score 10):

In bash you could write `exec 1>&-` in order to close the file descriptor known as stdout.

As Ignacio already said, EOF is not a character, so the question how to "echo EOF" doesn't make any sense in the first place. You can echo characters (bytes) or you can close a file descriptor, but you can never echo an EOF.